# MySQL: Why does query give NULL as a result of SUM?

Tags: mysql, null

Columns in the table `orders`  are as follows:

```
order_id, order_nr, created_at, order_value, payment_method
```

I would like to group orders from 2014 by month and check sum of their values depending on payment method.

I got a query:

```
SELECT 
  month(created_at),
  CASE WHEN payment_method = 'Cash' THEN sum(order_value) END as Cash,    
  CASE WHEN payment_method = 'CreditCard' THEN sum(order_value) END as CreditCard

FROM orders  
WHERE month(created_at) BETWEEN 5 AND 6 
AND year(created_at) = 2014 
GROUP BY month(created_at) 
ORDER BY order_value
```

**Problem:** For CreditCard the result is null.

**What I did:**
- I checked if there is any order where order_value is null - I didn't find any.
- I tried `COALESCE(sum(order_value),0)`
- I tried `sum(IFNULL(order_value,0))`
- I used this query:

```
  SELECT 
    month(created_at) as m,
    CASE WHEN payment_method = 'CreditCard' THEN sum(order_value) END as CreditCard
  FROM orders
  AND month(created_at) BETWEEN 5 AND 6
  AND year(created_at) = 2014
  GROUP BY month(created_at), payment_method /*here is the difference*/
  ORDER BY month(created_at) ASC
```

Gives me results like:

```
m | CreditCard
---------------
5 | NULL
5 | NULL
5 | 13256
6 | NULL
6 | NULL 
6 | 15356
```

Can you please explain to me 
A. from where does null come from? 
B. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want conditional aggregation -- the `case` statement goes *inside* the `sum()`:

```
SELECT month(created_at),
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_method = 'Cash' THEN order_value END) as Cash,    
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_method = 'CreditCard' THEN order_value END) as CreditCard
FROM orders  
WHERE month(created_at) BETWEEN 5 AND 6 AND year(created_at) = 2014 
GROUP BY month(created_at) 
ORDER BY SUM(order_value);
```

If you want `0` instead of `NULL`, you can add an `ELSE 0` to the `WHERE` clauses.

The problem with your query is that you have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  These values come from an *indeterminate* matching row.  The value of `payment_method` on that row is either `'Cash'` or `'Credit'` -- but only one value.  The above should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you - I will remember it. For sure "sum" without group by doesn't make sens in CASE statement ;) Thanks again!